# Rxjava chain more than one request

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I am new in concept of RxJava. 
I would like to chain some calls:

```
Observable<RoomList> listRoomsCall = mRoomServiceApi.listRooms();
```

//This call will get me RoomIds
Next step is to call for all RoomIds - request after request

```
mMeetingServiceApi.listMeetings(roomID, startsAtString, endsAtString, free))
```

How should I chain first call with next calls?

I thinkt that I should use `flatMap` and loop to call all requets but how to connect all responses on the end?

```
  listRoomsCall.flatMap(v -> {
            for (ExchangeRoom exchangeRoom : v.getExchangeRoomList()) {
               mMeetingServiceApi.listMeetings(roomID, startsAtString, endsAtString, free);
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn the inner list into an `Observable` and `flatMap` over it again:

```
listRoomsCall
.flatMapIterable(v -> v.getExchangeRoomList())
.flatMap(exchangeRoom -> {
    mMeetingServiceApi.listMeetings(roomID, startsAtString, endsAtString, free);
})
.subscribe(/* */);
```

or

```
listRoomsCall
.flatMap(v -> 
     Observable.fromIterable(v.getExchangeRoomList())
     .flatMap(exchangeRoom -> {
         mMeetingServiceApi.listMeetings(roomID, startsAtString, endsAtString, free);
     })
)
.subscribe(/* */);
```