# Upload files to Firebase Storage RxJava2

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage, rx-java2

I'm trying to upload files to Firebase Storage with RxJava2.
How do I make 1 method out of those 2?
I mean how do I concatenate those 2 requests?

Not able to do flatMap. Anyone can help to refactor it?

```
 private fun uploadPhotos() {
    val urisList = globalStorageViewModel.urisList

    storageRepository.uploadFiles(urisList)
            .subscribeBy(
                    onNext = { downloadFileUrl(it) },
                    onError = { onError(it) }
            ).apply {
                disposables.add(this)
            }
}
private fun downloadFileUrl(it: Pair<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, String>) {
    storageRepository.getDownloadUrl(it.first.storage)
            .subscribeBy(
                    onSuccess = { onFileUploaded(it) }
            ).apply {
                disposables.add(this)
            }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "How do I make 1 method out of those 2"?

Comment: Ankit, I mean "request concatination"

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51261975/1320616

Comment: Looks like an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47868628/1829281